# The Data Source value in the connection string

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, asp.net-mvc-5

I downloaded old project from google, and I have one question. How can i change database version, because actually is required Microsoft SQL 2012. Can u help me?

Error:

"The Data Source value in the connection string specifies an instance of SQL Server that is not installer."

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TaskManagerString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaskManagerDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=TaskManagerDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to :

```
`connectionString="Data Source=(local);AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaskManagerDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=TaskManagerDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`
```